# Sent items not saved in sent items folder in Outlook 365

Tags: imap, outlook-365

I recently moved a client domain over to a new server and to make sure that their email was moved across smoothly I:

- created a new IMAP email account for them in Office 365
- copied folder structure of old IMAP account over to the new account
- let everything synchronise

Everything works fine, and no emails were lost. However the problem the client is having is whenever they send an email it is not saved in their NEW sent items folder and instead it gets saved to their old account sent items folder.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: [This](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=45343) might help you.